# Premiere Export Issue With Still Photos

Tags: premiere, adobe, export

After years of using Adobe Photoshop & Premiere, I have finally run into a problem I can't solve, and I know it is very likely a relatively simple issue, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I have a series of still photos as part of a montage leading into the video portion of a project.  The source photos are fine but the Exported Project comes out all wrong - the stills are color shifted for some reason.  I am wondering if anyone out why[image]

Comment: Are the photos in .psd/.tif/.dng format? do they contain any filters/enchantments?

Comment: No - all JPG's - but I believe the issue is related to 'Scaling'